# Replace the empty list to something character such as "a"

Tags: python, list, dictionary, replace

I would like to replace the empty list within a dictionary_values to a random character such as "a".

My input:

```
k = [{'1': 'man'},
{'8': []},
{'3': 'chester'},
{'5': 'united'},
{'7': 'one'},
{'0': 'man'},
{'2': 'army'},
{'4': 'my'},
{'6': 'random'},
{'9': 'example'},
{'1': 'for'},
{'8': []},
{'3': 'asking'},
{'5': 'in'},
{'7': 'stack'},
{'0': 'over'},
{'2': 'flow'},
{'4': 'expert'},
{'6': 'people'},
{'9': 'yes'}]
```

My current code:

```
for i in k:
    for u, l in i.items():
        if "[]" in l:
            l.replace("[]", "a")
            print(l)
```

I try to run this code but get no output. I wanted to replace all the "[]" to "a" if possible. Is it possible to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this. -

```
k = [i if i.values() != [[]] else {i.keys()[0]:"a"} for i in k ]
print(k)
```

Result -

```
[{'1': 'man'},
 {'8': 'a'}, 
{'3': 'chester'},
 {'5': 'united'},
 {'7': 'one'},
 {'0': 'man'}, 
{'2': 'army'},
 {'4': 'my'}, 
{'6': 'random'}, 
{'9': 'example'}, 
{'1': 'for'}, 
{'8': 'a'}, 
{'3': 'asking'}, 
{'5': 'in'}, 
{'7': 'stack'}, 
{'0': 'over'}, 
{'2': 'flow'},
{'4': 'expert'}, 
{'6': 'people'}, 
{'9': 'yes'}]
```

Answer (score 2):

You have been trying to a replace on a `[]` type with a string, while you were supposed to update the value of a dictionary. Also you are doing a wrong condition checking in the line `if "[]" in l:` where l is a empty list which compared to the string `"[]"` which will never return `True`

```
for i in k:
    for u, l in i.items():
        if []==l:
            i[u]='a'
            print(l)
```

#### Output

> [{'1': 'man'},
>    {'8': 'a'},
>    {'3': 'chester'},
>    {'5': 'united'},
>    {'7': 'one'},
>    {'0': 'man'},
>    {'2': 'army'},
>    {'4': 'my'},
>    {'6': 'random'},
>    {'9': 'example'},
>    {'1': 'for'},
>    {'8': 'a'},
>    {'3': 'asking'},
>    {'5': 'in'},
>    {'7': 'stack'},
>    {'0': 'over'},
>    {'2': 'flow'},
>    {'4': 'expert'},
>    {'6': 'people'},
>    {'9': 'yes'}]

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in k:
    for u, l in i.items():
        if type(l) == list and not l:# Check If type is list and if its empty
            l = 'a'#just assign a instead of using replace which is used in string
            print(l)
```

You could check for the type of object as list instead of a string '[]'

Comment: Why not just compare with an empty list?  `if l == []`?

Comment: That's one way of doing so actually a better way, but I just wanted it to be a bit simpler to understand so I broke it into two [1. check the type 2. to check if its empty]

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 errors in your code.

1. The `if` condition in your code is wrong. Instead of checking `"[]"` - which is a `string`, you have to check `[]` which is a list.
2. Also, instead of replacing the value of the key which contains the empty list, you are appending to the empty list.

Use the following loop & it should work.

```
for i in k:
    for u, l in i.items():
        if l == []:
            i[u]="a"
```